# The font Georgia starts at different heights

Tags: css, fonts

I have the websafe font georgia that is beuatifull for what I want.

The only problem I am having is that the bottom of the font doesn't line up.

http://jsfiddle.net/JW7F8/

```
<style>
.georgia {
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:1.9em;
}​
</style>
<span class="georgia">
    1234567890
</span>
​
```

As you can see in the fiddle is that the 1,2,6 and 8 all start a bit higher than the rest.

**The question:**
How can I render georgia that it all starts on one line whilst still being able to set the site with *XX***em**.

I do not mind:

- splitting up the string
- setting different classes

I just need a workable solution that still allows for dynamic sizing.

Comment: Almost certainly next to impossible. The font is designed like that and you would have to do manual kerning dependant on the letter i.e. split every word into letters and span each letter then use javascript to read the letter and manually set position to top:-'n'px based on the character it is... unfeasible

Comment: Is the text used across the whole page or just headings etc? and to what level of browser support must you have?

Comment: Just as prices for products in a blue ball. But to have prices jumping up and down is just silly and doesn't look too professional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just the style of the font, technically all the font characters line up (if you highlight the text it will show the height of the font character).

You won't be able to consistently line up Georgia font even by splitting the font because the offset will have to vary depending on font size. This could be possible using `em`'s, but it would be hacky at least, and would be very difficult to get working consistently cross browser.

Also, changing the font position will cause [Kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) issues.

---

However, there is another similar font which Georgia was influenced from, which does line up:

> Georgia incorporates influences from Clarendon-style typefaces

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarendon_(typeface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarendon_%28typeface%29)

Comment: You could set the offset in ems which would scale on the point about lining up - my idea was purely speculative anyway and should never be attempted in anything other than POC code

Comment: I kow about clarendon... only problem is that it isn't websafe :(

Comment: well thats your options @MichaelDibbets

Answer (score 0):

For a websafe solution I ended up implementing this: **http://jsfiddle.net/JW7F8/2/**

```
<style>
.georgia {
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:1.9em;
}
.subitx {
        position:relative;
        top:0.18em;
        }
.subity {
        position:relative;
        top:0.13em;
        font-size:1.2em
        }​
</style>
<span class="georgia">
    <span class="subity">1</span><span class="subity">2</span>345<span class="subitx">6</span>7<span class="subitx">8</span>9<span class="subity">0</span>
</span>
```

Only shame is the fonts that are sized up are bolder than the rest.

I really wish there were more web safe fonts that work cross browser... *sigh*
​

Comment: Yea... Can't possibly put a commercial project on hold untill there is proper implementation of webfonts that render as good as native fonts. And if I didnd't the designer would bite off my head ;-)

Comment: BTW, I'm back to my hobby of the 90's cursing and swearing at IE for not supporting web standards... I hate conditional markup for ie...

Comment: IE must die! (including version 7... they say version 7 is the new 6 haha)

Comment: @PaulSullivan I couldn't agree more... only trouble is: Current webstats:Visits from IE: 42%, of which... **9.0** 62.08%, **8.0** 32.22%, **7.0** 4.51% and even... *-gasp-* **6.0** 0.55%(didn't know people can actually work with 6.0 nowadays...)

Comment: It's almost certainly business users on legacy systems... It's getting to the point though where I put a 'you're on an unsupported browser... upgrade or see bugs' but I have the final say on it so I don't have to justify to anyone...

Comment: If only I could do that... But that way I'd exclude a large swat of potential customers...

Comment: 2% of 5% (or 0.55% for just IE6) seems acceptable losses (1/20 or 1/200).

Comment: I agree with that, but with the volume of visitors it is still nice to make it at least "seem" presentable.

Answer (score 0):

The Georgia font has old-style digits, i.e. digits that vary in height and may extend below the baseline too.

Most fonts that people use on web page have modern-style “lining” digits, all digits being of equal height, roughly the same as uppercase letters.

Some fonts contain both. It has relatively recently become possible to choose between such alternatives in CSS, in several browsers, using `font-feature-settings`. But Georgia has only old-style digits.

It is best to choose a different font if you think that such a fundamental feature is not suitable for your text.

However, on WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari), using `@font-face` (for local fonts, not embedded) and `unicode-range`, you could specify that digits be taken from another font. It’s technically simple but not really a good idea:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Georgiax;
  src: local("Times New Roman");
  unicode-range: U+30-39;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Georgiax;
  src: local("Georgia");
  unicode-range: U+0-29, U+40-10FFFF;
}
```

Then you would just use `font-family: Georgiax` as if it were a real font family. But as said, this technique is not supported by other than WebKit browsers, and taking digits from another font means a typographic blunder.

P.S. Georgia is not web-safe. No font is. You won’t find it on an Android, for example.